# How do you print the value of a string variable in R

Tags: r, loops

this has probably been covered before but i can't quite get to the answer.

I have the following code:

```
for (i in c(1:7)){
  assign(paste("day_", i, sep = ""), i)
  print(paste("day_",i, sep = ""))
}

[1] "day_1"
[1] "day_2"
[1] "day_3"
[1] "day_4"
[1] "day_5"
[1] "day_6"
[1] "day_7"
```

I assign each day of the week, then i want to print the value of the variable.
At the moment it just prints the string day_1, day_2, etc.
I want it to print the value of the day_1 variable. e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc

The code does more than this but I have simplified it.

Comment: In your third line, use `get` to get the actual value from a string variable name... `print(get(paste("day_",i, sep = "")))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the follwing code :

```
get("your_string")
```

Hope that will helps

Gottavianoni

Answer (score 0):

`paste` returns a character vector, you can use `eval` & `parse` :

`eval(parse(text = paste0("day_", i))`